# Why RDFConnection blocked when I'm connecting it to fuseki after several times?

Tags: rdf, jena, fuseki

I'm using RDFConnectionFactory to connect to a remote fuseki server in a web application using Spring Boot, but the Connection get blocked when I try to connect to it 5 times (each restart always success 5 times and then blocked afterwards). Is there something wrong with my code?

```
public RDFResult query(String queryString) {
    RDFConnection connection = RDFConnectionFactory.connect(host);
    System.out.println("CONNECTED");
    RDFResult result;
    try {
        connection.begin(ReadWrite.READ);
        System.out.println("TRANSACTION BEGIN");
        System.out.println(connection.isInTransaction());
        ResultSet rs = connection.query(queryString).execSelect();
        result = new RDFResult();
        result.setVarNames(rs.getResultVars());
        while (rs.hasNext()) {
            QuerySolution qs = rs.next();
            List<String> row = result.getVarNames().stream().map(e -> qs.get(e).toString()).collect(Collectors.toList());
            result.getResultSet().add(row);
        }
        connection.end();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    } finally {
        connection.abort();
        connection.close();
        System.out.println("asdfasdf");
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm solved this! execSelect require explicit close...